# Get website data from specific data-field [VBA-Excel]

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I have a list of URLs and which URLs have contact info. All URLs have the same web structure.  I need to get data from this specific data-field ="hs_analytics_first_url":

```
<input tabindex="1" class="hs-input navigable" type="text" data-field="hs_analytics_first_url" value="http://www.trekksoft.com/en/" disabled="" readonly="">
```

The problem: there are lots of class="hs-input navigable" and it's position is not static. The only way to identify those fields is with data-field, but I don't know how to get data from data-field.

What I have so far only works with 1 URL because it's not always the 4th class item:

```
Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = Trim(ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("hs-input navigable")(4).Value)
```

Can someone help me with that? If this information helps, I trying to grab data from Hubspot website.

Comment: Hi, depending on which Office version you have installed there should be a context menu for tables installed on IE called "Export to excel". However that extension uses vbscript and will not work in IE11 'Edge' Mode. Hubspot renders in IE11 Edge mode...so you can't use it...
Workaround: open Excel and Import the data from the excel data menu.
or
Use the Emulation tab to change the Emulation mode when your at Hubspot to IE10 (there is a 'persist emulation mode' button on the Emulation tab of dev tools to allow you to retain that emulation setting while navigating the site...no close dev tool

Comment: @RobParsons Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't help much. I'm looking for a way to automate this process with VBA. I have a list with 100+ contacts with diferent URLs and do that one by one isn't an option :P

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = Trim(ie.Document.querySelector( _
            "input[data-field='hs_analytics_fi‌​rst_url']").value)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. When I run your code with VBA I have this error: "Run-time error '424': Object required".

Comment: When I tried in a document with just that HTML fragment it worked, so I'm not sure what the issue is.  Can you provide a URL for testing?